# How to make importxml not skip over empty nodes?

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets, xml-parsing

I'm using importxml Google Sheets as a simple web scraper. When I run it on an xml file, everything works fine except that it skips over nodes with no text. For example, it imports text into a cell for

```
<middlename>Name</middlename>
```

but not for

```
<middlename/>
```

(i.e. when the node has no text). I tried using an if-statement to fix this, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Based on my searching, I don't think that this is currently possible. I would be very interested in finding a work around as well.